# Intellij open file or project view doesn't show anything

Tags: intellij-idea

If I try to open a file or project in IntelliJ ultimate 2020.3.3 the editor does not show anything.

[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89lPL.png)

Comment: Have you tried to click on "Refresh"?

Comment: If  I click refresh nothing happens. Additionally I cleared the cache and reinstalled IntelliJ but the outcome remains the same.

Comment: Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?